# What is the probability of at least one of the parts functioning successfully?

Tags: probability, independence

I have a practice question for a test which is:

> The probability that a certain critical part of a spaceship working
> during a flight is determined to be 0.99. Since the engineers are
> reluctant to risk the probability 0.01 of failure, they insert two
> more of the same part in parallel. This means that failure occurs if
> and only if all three parts fail. Assume that all three parts operate
> independently. What is the probability of at least one of the parts
> functioning successfully?

I know that to answer the question, I would have to do 1 - (probability of no parts functioning successfully). However I'm a little lost on how to find the probability of no parts functioning.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the three parts are assumed to operate independently, the probability of all three parts failing together is just the product of the probabilities of individual failing.

More formally: Let $X_j, \, j = 1,2,3, $ be independent Bernoulli(p) random variables (with  p = 0.01, if we want $X_j = 1$ to mean failure of part $j$).
Then $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1, X_2 = 1, X_3 = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1) \mathbb{P}(X_2 = 1) \mathbb{P}(X_3 = 1) = p^3$.